# Elastic Search - Count of items for specific criteria - Curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Curl command to get count of items for specific criteria.

Something like given below.

```
 curl -XGET -k 'https://localhost:9200/myelastic/_search?pretty' -d '
   {
      "query": { "match": { "status": "Disconnected" } },
      "size": 1000
   }'
```

Is it possible to limit the output to only specific fields and not everything which comes back like score, hits and the entire payload

Just found using _source[] one can limit the fields returned. Still looking for suppressing _index, _score from output for easy processing

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can use `_source` to limit fields and You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) to avoid stuff like `_index`, `_score` etc.

```
    curl -XGET -k 'https://localhost:9200/myelastic/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source' -d '
   {
      "query": { "match": { "status": "Disconnected" } },
      "size": 1000
   }'
```

Comment: works to filter! I think I found count after devouring elastic search docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

Comment: ohh, I thought you were looking to limit output